# layoutParams.setMargins - setMargins doesn't work in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I followed and coded along a [freecodecamp android app tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2DBDZKkLss&t=1554s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org) at 34:02 the same code works on the video but mine doesn't work and androdid studio higlight it with red under line[my code which showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKS4N.png)[code in video which doesn't show error ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoqhG.png)

me followed and coded along a [freecodecamp android app tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2DBDZKkLss&t=1554s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org) at 34:02 the same code works on the video but mine doesn't work and androdid studio higlight it with red under line[my code which showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKS4N.png)[code in video which doesn't show error ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoqhG.png), if no one helps there is no other option for me but to skip to next tutorial but i love that tutorial he is explaining things very good. In that point only i got error.Kindly help me to resolve it

Comment: Could you share the error message? (hover over the red undeline and it should appear)